# Filter Map keys into a set

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a map `Map<String,EnrollmentData>` which maps student ID to his data.
The student id need to be filtered on certain EnrollmentData attributes ,and returned as a Set.

```
Map<String, EnrollmentData> studentData = .........;
if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(studentData )){
        Set<String> idSet = studentData .entrySet().stream()
                     .filter(x -> x.getValue().equals(...) )
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet( x -> x.getKey()));
}
```

However,this gives me a compilation error in the toSet [ Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (( x) -> {}) ] .
What needs to be done here.

Comment: Alternative: `studentData.values().removeIf(v -> !v.equals(…)); Set<String> idSet = studentData.keySet();` Of course, only applicable if `studentData` is mutable and not needed in its original form anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the filtering, you have a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, EnrollmentData>>`. Collecting with `toSet()` (which accepts no arguments) would collect `Entry<String, EnrollmentData>`s, but you want to map each element to their key prior to collecting instead.

You must first map the elements of the resulting stream to the `Entry`'s key:

```java
.filter(yourFilterFunction)
.map(Map.Entry::getKey)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```